# HTML sandboxed iframe - redirect parent call to the same iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I need to embed a thirdparty webapp inside another HTML page. The problem is that this webapp includes calls to window.top so doesn't work inside my iframe.

For example in this code I want 'www.google.com' to load inside the iframe without changing the code of 'FramePage.html':

```
<!--ParentPage.html-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  Parent Page
  <iframe src="FramePage.html" sandbox></iframe>
</body>
</html>

<!--FramePage.html-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  FRAME
  <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_top">hello</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just remove the `target` attribute from `FramePage.html`?

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to HTML5 instead of the (quite outdated) transitional doctype you're currently using, you can use the "sandbox" attribute to your `<iframe>` which among other things disables the ability of an iframe to change the location of the framing page.  (I do see you have that attribute in place already, but it will have no effect in pre-HTML5 documents.)

The options for the "sandbox" property are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe). (All of them reduce the amount of restrictions placed on the framed site; if all you want is to prevent window.top navigation, include all the options except "allow-top-navigation".)

This will not create the behavior you want, though: it will cause those `target="_top"` links to simply not work at all, instead of causing them to stay inside the frame.

Beyond this, it is not possible to change the functionality of a framed third-party site that you don't control.